# How can I get divs inside a div to continue on a new row when the current row (screen horizontally) is full?

Tags: css

I have following html in a asp.net MVC project.

In my layout page:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:225px; margin-left:10px;">
    <div id="datepicker"></div>

    <div id="typ" style="margin-right:10px;">
        @Html.Action("_GetSomeContent", "Controller")
    </div>
</div>

<div id="body">

    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>

</div>
```

Inside the RenderBody i have a page containing a loop that outputs a number of divs with a bit of content:

```
<div style="float:left;width:186px;">
...
....
...
</div>

<div style="float:left;width:186px;">
...
....
...
</div>
```

css I think is contributing to the problem:

```
html {
background-color: #e2e2e2;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;   
white-space:nowrap;

}
```

For some reason when the page is full horizontally the div is continuing on the same line so that scrolling horizontally is needed, not placed below as I what them to.

I'm guessing it's because of the white-space:nowrap; in html. But when I remove white-space:nowrap the whole `<div id="body">` is put on below the first div in the layout page and I want this two divs to always be side by side.

How can I get the divs inside `<div id="body">` to continue on a new row when the current row (screen horizontally) is full?

**Update**

Someone answerd but then removed something that workted. I had forgotten to set a width to the #body

Comment: That was me with the `body { width: 100%; }` ... I didnt think it was achieving what you were trying to do but i added it to my answer below as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It may be as easy as setting the width of the body: `body {width: 100%;}`**

But I think using `display: table;` will end up being a more robust way to solve your issues.
Try these styles:

```
body {
    display: table;
}
#body { 
    display: table-cell;
}
.firstDiv { 
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align: top;
    width:225px; 
    margin-left:10px;   
}
```

Using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` allows you to take advantage of the nature of tables to fill the remaining space in their parent container (in this case the `<body>`)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/FL629/)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the white-space:nowrap and add display:inline-block to your divs... I think that's what you're looking for.  It's hard to tell with the information given.  DIVs are display:block by default, so they won't line up horizontally unless you add the style to display:inline or display: inline-block;

Here is some more information on HTML Blocks http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp